# Python static variable generator function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using the following function to generate a static variable in Python:

```
 #Static variable generator function
def static_num(self):
    k = 0
    while True:
        k += 1
        yield k
```

When I am calling this function from main code:

```
 regression_iteration = self.static_num()
 print " Completed test number %s  %s \n\n" % (regression_iteration, testname)
```

I get this output:

```
  "Completed test number <generator object static_num at 0x027BE260>  be_sink_ncq"
```

Why I am not getting an incremented integer? Where is my static variable generator going wrong?

**Edit:**

I am calling the function static_num in the following manner now:

```
regression_iteration = self.static_num().next()
```

But it returns only '1' since the value of 'k' is being initialized to zero every time the function is called. Therefore, I do not get the required output 1,2,3,4 .... on every call of the function

Comment: What are you trying to do with this generator?  And how does your concept of a static number work?

Comment: "*Yield is a keyword that is used like return, except the function will return a generator.*" You are printing the whole object not just the values. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) post.

Comment: When you say *static variable*, do you mean a variable that is shared between all instances of a class?  If so, how does your generator help accomplish this?

Comment: Similar to the concept of static variable in C, I need a variable whose value  will remain unchanged when a function is called repeatedly. At the end of the function, I will increase the value of the variable, so that in the next function call it gets an incremented value and does not get reset to zero like an automatic variable

Comment: Why not just *not modify* the value inside the function.  I may be misunderstanding, but it seems like you're doing significantly more work than necessary.

Comment: @jedwards, I am trying to increment the value of a variable (regression_iteration) on every call of a function. The variable has to reside inside the function. So, it has to be a static variable incrementing from 1 to 2 to 3 and so on....

Comment: I don't think you have a clear grasp on the scoping rules.  But without more context, it's hard to give you a great answer.

Comment: From your edit, it looks like you could just drop in my 3-line `counter` function and write `regression_iteration = counter()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its hard to say whether you *need* to use this approach -- I *strongly* doubt it, but instead of a generator you could abuse using mutable types as default initializers:

```
def counter(init=[0]):
    init[0] += 1
    return init[0]

x = counter()
print(x)  # 1
print(x)  # 1
print(x)  # 1
x = counter()
print(x)  # 2
print(x)  # 2
print(x)  # 2
# ... etc
```

The return value of `counter` increases by one on each call, starting at 1.

Comment: jedwards, this worked perfectly !! Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: @user3565150 No problem, and sorry for the confusion in comments.  And thank *you* for pushing me over 10k rep :)

Comment: Its fine, you have helped me a lot before, I can take this little pain :)

Answer (score 0):

The yield keyword convert your function return value from int to an int generator, so you have to use "for i in self.static_num()" to access the int.If you want to access the generator one by one. Use next function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by static you meant static to the class, the best way to do this is to use a class variable and a [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
class Static_Number_Class(object):
    _static_number = 0
    @classmethod
    def static_number(cls):
        cls._static_number += 1
        return cls._static_number
```

If this is just a stand alone function you could use a closure instead:

```
def Counter():
    n = 0
    def inner():
        n += 1
        return n
    return inner

count = Counter()
x = count()
print(x) # 1
x = count()
print(x) # 2
```