# Change attribute after each object calling

Tags: python, class, attributes, call

I'm trying to figure out how to change some value after each call of the object. 
I thougt that **call**() function is executed after each call.

This should be a simple counter class which decreases value attribute after being called.

```
class counter():
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value

    def __call__(self):
        self.value -= 1

count = counter(50)
print count.value
print count.value

>> 50 
>> 50 <-- this should be 49
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) is called when you call your instance as a function. i.e after executing `count()`,  `count.value` would be 49. You might be looking for [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)

Comment: @Matt: I tried to use __getattribute__ but still the same. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Do you want count.value to decrease by 1 every time it is accessed?

Comment: @Matt Yes I want exactly that.

Comment: does it need to be a class or do you just need a counter?

Comment: @Matt I've started because I needed a counter but now, I'm very curious if something like that is possible. So I want it to be a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not committed to classes, you could use a function and abuse using mutable-types-as-default-initializers:

```
def counter(init=None, container=[0]):
    container[0] -= 1
    if init is not None: container[0] = init
    return container[0]


x = counter(100)
print(x) # 100
print( counter() )  # 99
print( counter() )  # 98
print( counter() )  # 97
# ...
```

Call `counter` with a single argument to set/initialize the counter.  Since initialization is actually the first call to the function, it will return that number.

Call `counter` with no arguments to get the "next value".

(Very similar to what I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092576/python-static-variable-generator-function/29093043#29093043))

Alternatively, for a syntax closer to what you had in your question, use [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, init):
        self.val = init

    @property
    def value(self):
        val = self.val
        self.val -= 1
        return val

count = Counter(50)

print(count.value)  # 50
print(count.value)  # 49
print(count.value)  # 48
print(count.value)  # 47
#...
```

Here, you're creating a `Counter` object called `count`, then every time you call `count.value` it returns the current value and prepares itself for a future call by decrementing it's internal `val` attribute.

Again, the first time you request the `value` attribute, it returns the number you initialized it with.

If, for some reason, you want to "peek" at what the next call to `count.value` will be, without decrementing it, you can look at `count.val` instead.

Comment: You should a look into [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29). This is basically what you are doing by using `[]` as a default argument, but by using a closure instead, you can use your counter function to create multiple counters. Take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29244937/4687645)

Answer (score 3):

`__call__` is only invoked when you call the object using `()`

To invoke this behaviour you'd have to do

```
class counter():
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value

    def __call__(self):
        print 'called'
        self.value -= 1

count = counter(50)
print count.value
count()
print count.value
```

This may not be exactly what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

[Use the property decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

```
class counter:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value + 1

    @property
    def value(self):
        self._value -= 1
        return self._value

count = Counter(50)
print(count.value)  # 50
print(count.value)  # 49
```

Alternatly, you could use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29244937/4687645):

```
def Counter(n):
    n += 1
    def inner():
        n -= 1
        return n
    return inner
```

Though this has to be called every time you want to use it

```
count1 = Counter(50)
count2 = Counter(50)
print(count1())  # 50
print(count1())  # 49
print(count2())  # 50
print(count2())  # 49
print(count1())  # 48
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a custom **call**() method in the meta-class allows custom behaviour when the class is called, e.g. not always creating a new instance.As no new class instance is created **call** gets called instead of **init**.So do this to get the desired result

```
print count.value
count()
print count.value
```