# Call method modification issue

Tags: python, class, oop, call, init

According to this answer [Change attribute after each object calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244699/change-attribute-after-each-object-calling), I thought that call method should do something to its instance everytime its called. I'm trying to use this in my code but I'm wrong somewhere.

```
class switcher():
    current_index = -1

    def __call__(self):
        self.current_index +=1

sw = switcher()
print sw.current_index
print sw.current_index
```

**output:** -1

**output:**  -1

I think that it should return this:

**output:**  0

**output:**  1

because it increments the `current_index` value everytime the **sw** instance is called.

Obviously I'm wrong, could you tell me where is the problem please?

Comment: You never call any switcher instance in this code.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you really want to do but you need to actually call the instance which you are not  doing:

```
sw = switcher() # creates instance, does not call __call__ in your class
sw() # call/increment calling the instance 
print(sw.current_index)
sw() # call/increment calling the instance 
print(sw.current_index)
0 # after first sw() call 
1  # after second sw() call
```

The `__call__` makes your instance callable, if you don't call the instance then it does nothing. Creating an instance has nothing to do with `__call__`

The property approach in the answer you linked to seems to be what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, that has nothing to do with the problem, it is completely irrelevant to the issue

Comment: No I'm not using __call__ and __init__ interchangeably, I do know that init is called when and only when the instance is being created. I thought that __call__ is being called everytime I "use" the instance of the method. It means whenever I use (I thought call) attribute or a method.

Comment: @Milan, no call is used when you call the instance, it makes the object callable, it does not mean it gets called every time you use the instance to access the attribute. Using a property is about the only reasonable way to do what you want

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, there is nothing in the question to suggest the variable should not be shared

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for explaining it. Is there something I can use to change the attribute everytime I do anything with the instance like accessing the attribute or using a method? I know that I can use __@property but Is there a method like call and init which can do that?

Comment: @Milan, you could simply decrement in the methods but as far as decrementing when you access the attribute directly goes, there is no simple way I can think of doing it

Comment: @Milan, what is it that you are actually trying to do, is there a specific reason you want the behaviour?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Let's clean up the comments.

Answer (score 1):

First: the current_index attribute belongs to the class, not to the object instance, as you require. 
You need to assign it within

```
__init__(self)
```

Second: call the object instance, as described in the previous answer.

Comment: It's not a matter of convention. Class and instance attributes behave quite differently. He says he wants to operate on the instance

Comment: Although this is not the main problem I agree that the attribute should be an instance attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You do not understand the difference between the constructor and the caller methods of a class:

```
__init__ := 'instance is created when class is invoked, Switcher()'
__call__ := 'func is executed when instance is invoked, switcher()'
```

```py
class Switcher():

    def __init__(self):
        self.current_index = -1

    def __call__(self):
        self.current_index += 1
```

```py
switcher = Switcher() # instance created calling __init__ -> current_index = -1
```

```py
switcher() # instance just been invoked, calling __call__ -> current_index = 0
```

Comment: Bear in mind that you should really just use a property.